# Calling a C function defined in another file

Tags: c, file, function

I know this question has a lot of answers, but I am always getting an error on gcc c1.c

```
c1.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

no matter what I try.

This is c1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "c.h"

int main()
{
    printf("F %d\n",f());
}
```

THis is c2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(void) {return 7;}

int main()
{
    printf("S %d\n",f());
}
```

This is c.h

```
int f(void);
```

**How could I get it working?** Actually, I was getting this error in a big program that is modelled like this. I guess this is the way to do it.
(And yes, main should return 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have problems, since you have two different `main` functions defined, but the general way to do this is a link-time issue:

```
gcc -c c1.c
gcc -c c2.c
gcc c1.o c2.o
```

All you need to do is figure out which main you want, and remove the unwanted one.

You could do something like:

```
gcc -Dmain=blah -c c1.c
gcc -c c2.c
gcc c1.o c2.o
```

Comment: c2.o: In function `main':
c2.c:(.text+0xb): multiple definition of `main'
c1.o:c1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Well, you really can't have two mains, can you?  If you want 'f' to be defined, put it in a file without a `main`.

Comment: Any way without putting it in a different file because the original program has a situation like this.

Comment: Use a preprocessor directive to redefine main.

Comment: BTW: *always* compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info). Then learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`). At this point, you probably should learn how to use `make`. See [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/273582/40065)